# sumar dos numeros de un array con bucles anidados

Tags: array

La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número entero llamado 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.

Ej:
sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13
sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos
números del arreglo.
Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
Ej:
sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos
veces por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso.

mi codigo:

```js
let n=6;
let array=[8,7,4,12,2,10]; // quiero que sume 4+2=6
function sumArray(array,n) {
  let numbers=array;
  let cont=0;
  for (let i=0;i<numbers[2];i++) {
    for (let j=0;j<numbers.length;j++) {
      if (numbers[2]<numbers[j]) {
        result=numbers[2]+numbers[j];
        true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
sumArray(array,n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer array lo comienzas en i=0 y el segundo en j=i+1, asi nunca repites el mismo.

```js
let n=6;
let array=[8,7,4,12,2,10];

function sumArray(array,n) {
  for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    for (let j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {
      if (n == (array[i] + array[j])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(sumArray(array,n));
```